# Delphi IDE wizard to automatically generate actions from menu items?

Tags: delphi, ide, action, delphi-xe2, menuitem

At design-time inside the IDE, is there a quick 'n' easy trick to automatically generate actions from several menu items and then apply these actions back to the menu items?

Comment: *Converting* would mean the original thing ceases to exist afterward, and that doesn't make any sense. Maybe you mean you want a way to generate an action from a menu item? Such a task might involve transferring responsibility of several of the menu item's property to the new action, and then associating the action with the menu item.

Comment: From an English dictionary: "to convert: change in nature, purpose, or function; especially undergo a chemical change; "The substance converts to an acid""
The GENERATED action should then immediately be applied to the menu item, so in fact the menu item's properties would be changed a.k.a. converted.

Comment: Dictionary definition aside (somewhat rude of you, BTW), your question makes no sense. You're asking if the IDE can figure out, based on existing menu items (and presumably the events you've attached to them), what actions you might want to create, create them, and then attach them back the original menu item? If so, no - there is no existing functionality that will do this for you.

Comment: @KenWhite Why getting emotional? Your question is just a resume of my own question. The words "there is no existing functionality that will do this" would have been enough. Or are there any other problems on your side I don't know?

Comment: Where do you see "emotional" in what I wrote? Your posting the dictionary definition was somewhat rude (Rob and others here are aware of the meaning of "convert"). I stated your question in somewhat clearer terms (IMO) to make sure I understood it, and then answered it. There's absolutely no emotion involved, and the only problem on my side is that taxes where I live are much too high. :-)

Comment: Would be so good if there was! Theoretically possible by processing the DFM entries?

Answer (score 1):

The drop down of the action inside the Object Inspector allows you to create a new action which will automatically be connected, but you have to set the actions properties manually and implement the event handles separately.

Comment: Which is exactly what I said in my comment: There's no functionality in the IDE to magically create an action from a menu item and move all of the properties and event handlers to that new action and remove them from the menu item.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be available in Delphi 10.2. It was there in Delphi XE4, but apparently has been removed in later versions.